# All Google API Calls From Our Office Time Out

Tags: api, dns, out, timed

We have a small office with 20+ computers that are about 80/20 split Macs vs. PCs.  I am a web developer by trade who manages our little network but am, by no means, a networking/DNS expert.

That being said, we are having trouble in that every single web site we visit (stackoverflow.com included) that makes a call to a Google API takes *forever* to load.  They all get stuck with a statusbar message such as: "Connecting to fonts.googleapis.com, ajax.googleapis.com, developers.google.com etc..."  Eventually, the api call times out and the site will then load without it.  Sometimes we get a pop-up error "accounts.google.com" failed to respond.  In fact, when we finally get Stack Overflow to load this message is at the top of the page: "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

This seems to be only happening on our internal network.  For instance, we can connect laptops, phones and tablets to LTE/mobile networks and they load up the same sites fine.

Oddly enough, Google.com, itself, loads fine.  As do Gmail and Google Docs.

When I ping 'fonts.googleapis.com' from both inside the network and from our firewall I get "Request timed out" for 'googleapis.l.google.com' [74.125.70.95].

I have tried deleting all Google entries from our DNS server, an old Windows 2003 Small Biz Server, which sometimes results in 'googleapis.l.google.com' getting a different IP address from our ISP which alleviates the issue temporarily.  But, it seems eventually this same IP of 74.125.70.95 will get tacked on to the API URL and we're back in the same boat.

I tried changing the DNS server address of our Win2003 SBS server, itself, away from our ISP's address to both OpenDNS and Google's own DNS server but this hasn't helped.

This has been happening for about a month.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this article:

http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/2450/2750/4350/120934.aspx

Essentially it details something I hadn't thought about.  My firewall's Country Blocking feature.  Even though the particular IP I had trouble with seemed to belong to Google here in the US, it may have been routed through China (or my firewall's IP address tables are outdated) so traffic was being blocked.

I've adjusted FW rules to allow this IP and all is well.